# Parse CSV with embedded quotes on mixed string

Tags: regex, csv, perl

I have looked around, but cannot find a tidy working solution to this. I have been trying to use TEXT:CSV_XS so this is not about merely doing something the hard way with a regex. I may not be able to easily install TEXT::CSV, but I do have the XS version.

I simply need to parse into csv fields, which I will later break down into kv pairs.

```
use Text::CSV_XS;
use Data::Dumper;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ allow_loose_quotes => 1, 
                               allow_whitespace => 1,  
                               eol => $/ });

my $str3 = '09/11/2016 22:05:00 +0000, search_name="ThreatInjection - Rule", search_now=1473644880.000, search="bunchof|stuff1,bunch%of-stuff2", count=100';

my $status  = $csv->parse($str3);
my @details = $csv->fields();
print $csv->error_diag ();
print Dumper(\@details);
```

Resulting output is:

```
$VAR1 = [
      '09/11/2016 22:05:00 +0000',
      'search_name="ThreatInjection - Rule"',
      'search_now=1473644880.000',
      'search="bunchof|stuff1',
      'bunch%of-stuff2"',
      'count=100'
    ];
```

So, the ask is to get search="bunchof|stuff1,bunch%of-stuff2" to remain in one field. I am sure the answer is simple, but, a bit stumped none the less. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with with [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) which has been included in the standard Perl distribution since forever.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::ParseWords;
use Data::Dumper;

my $str3 = '09/11/2016 22:05:00 +0000, search_name="ThreatInjection - Rule", search_now=1473644880.000, search="bunchof|stuff1,bunch%of-stuff2", count=100';

my @details = parse_line(',\s*', 1, $str3);

print Dumper \@details;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '09/11/2016 22:05:00 +0000',
          'search_name="ThreatInjection - Rule"',
          'search_now=1473644880.000',
          'search="bunchof|stuff1,bunch%of-stuff2"',
          'count=100'
        ];
```